# Log the output of a process running as a SystemD service with screen

Tags: systemd, logs, services, gnu-screen

I am running a minecraft server as a systemd service with the following service script

```
Description=MC Server: %i
After=network.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/opt/minecraft/%i

User=minecraft
Group=minecraft

Restart=always
RestartSec=30

StandardOutput=append:ServiceConsoleOut.log
StandardError=append:ServiceConsoleErr.log

ExecStart=/usr/bin/screen -DmS mc-%i java -Xms48G -Xmx48G -jar paper.jar --nogui

ExecStop=/usr/bin/screen -p 0 -S mc-%i -X eval 'stuff "say SERVER SHUTTING DOWN IN 5 SECONDS..."\015'
ExecStop=/bin/sleep 5
ExecStop=/usr/bin/screen -p 0 -S mc-%i -X eval 'stuff "save-all"\015'
ExecStop=/usr/bin/screen -p 0 -S mc-%i -X eval 'stuff "stop"\015'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I want to capture the output of the console as a log and tried with the redirecting with StandardOutput and StandardError but obviously that didn't work.
I am sure that this is possible but i cannot remember how it needs to be done. Can someone provide me with the necessary insight to how to do it?

Comment: Don't do this. Use `journalctl --follow --unit=minecraft.service`.

Comment: @paladin THat only works for looking at the systemd logs but screen is not outputting anything into journalctl

Comment: why are you using `screen`? that's what breaks your logging here. Simply don't do that. Daemons shouldn't be logging to interactive terminal emulators like `screen`.

Comment: @MarcusMüller The reason for screen is to be able to access the interactive shell of the admin console.

Comment: then that's not what you should be logging, as far as I can tell. Sorry to be of not much help there, but it would sound like whatever server program this is, it probably has a separate logging facility that should actually be used.